# How to wait state before rendering in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I use 'React Context' to pass state `user` to the child components.

The problem: Everytime you reload the page, the state `user` value is null. This cause the page briefly redirect to `/login` before redirecting to '/dashboard`. This will prevent user from accessing a page manually.

The goal: How to wait for state `user` before rendering?

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) setUser(user);
      else setUser(null);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthDataContext.Provider value={user}>
        <Layout>
          <Routes />
        </Layout>
      </AuthDataContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

routes

```
export const Routes = () => {
  const user = useContext(AuthDataContext);
  if (user) {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/list" component={List} />
        <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={LogIn} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/passwordreset" component={PasswordReset} />
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
};
```

authdata

```
import React from "react";

export const AuthDataContext = React.createContext(null);
```

edit: quick fix
App.js

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("first");
```

routes

```
else if (user === "first") return null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a component that initiates API call and renders some kind of loader while user is waiting for a response. Then in case user is authenticated you can render regular application routes, if not – render routes for `sign in`, `sign up` and so on.

Comment: I see, great idea. I applied a quick fix, now state `user` have 3 possible value `firebase user data, null, or first`. If I am not wrong, if I add loading bar, this will cause `routes` to have 3 possible return? ps: sorry, I am a slow learner, this is my 4th day of React, and about 120 days of programming.

Comment: It's more or less same thing that I meant. But your state data structure can be a bit more accurate at least you can store a user itself which might be missing unlit you request it, and  the request state, like pending or failure, so you can easily decide render, routes or even error message.  But in overall I see you understood my idea.